How do I open a dialog from an Outlook add-in?
I am attempting to open a dialog form my Outlook add-in. I want to to open from a command in the ribbon, circumventing going through a Taskpane first and just do it directly.
I am having loads of trouble developing a debugging an add-in in the first place.
I believe I have added the content and the references to my dialog (both .js and .html files) in the manifest and webpack.config. But nothing happens.
I have fiddled a lot with configuring the references and configurations in the manifest. I am using a unified manifest.json btw (the other xml setup never seemed to work for me).
I expected that when I click the command, a dialog appears, but nothing.
EDIT:
I believe it is related to the origin of the host page. I have managed to launch a dialog from within a Taskpane.
My functions looks like this:
function openDialog() {
    Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
        "https://localhost:3000/dialog.html",
        { height: 50, width: 50, displayInFrame: true },
        function (asyncResult) {
        var dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function (args) {
            if ("message" in args) {
                if (args.message === "close") {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            } else {
                console.error("Error received: ", args.error);
            }
        });
        }
    );
}  

It is a simple dialog with just a close button.
Debugging is using webpack and running with npm through the VS Code debugger.
The debugging output is cluttered with a bunch of stuff from Outlook Web, and nothing in the regular Outlook Desktop. But on the Web edition, it does write the document required a 'TrustedScript' or 'TrustedScriptURL'. But it is difficult to determine if it triggered by my add-in or by other background stuff. I have added various relevant domains to the manifest.json (which by MS documentation said would be sufficient to allow different origins).
However, I am just unable to trigger the dialog launch from my command.
EDIT 2:
I have fingured out that it does work in the regular desktop version of Outlook using the command. It would appear that my issue if limited to the Outlook Web version, since it is running in a browser environment (even on desktop). That means that there is a security issue with the Cross Origin stuff. But I don't know how to work around that in Outlook. MS has very limited documentation regarding this. It just says that the domain has to be the same. But is it even possible to weave my custom dialog.html in to the domain (or allowed domain) that the base webview is running?
